# Adding Calendar Events from loop.

Tags: android, json, calendar

I was following [this](https://applandeo.com/blog/material-calendar-view-customized-calendar-widget-android/) tutorial for creating agenda view calendar. 
It is working fine but what i need to show are the events from the server. 
From server it is showing only the last event, i tried putting   `mCalendarView.setDate(myEventDay.getCalendar());` within and outside the for loop but it had the same effect.

```
                Calendar cal = Calendar. getInstance();

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    // Get current json object

                    JSONObject details = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String dateTime = details.getString("date_from");
                    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(dateTime, "T");
                    String date = tokens.nextToken();
                    String time = tokens.nextToken();
                    Date mdate = parseDateToddMMyyyy(Date);

                    String event_title = details.getString("event_title");
                    String event_description = details.getString("event_description");
                    String locationName = details.getString("event_location");
                    String event_lat = details.getString("lat");
                    String event_long = details.getString("longi");
                    String eTime = details.getString("from_time");


                    myEventDay = new MyEventDay(cal, eTime,
                            R.drawable.ic_shape, event_title, event_description, "",
                            "",
                            "lat "+event_lat+ " long "  ,LocationName);

                    myEventDay.setCalendar(cal);
                    myEventDay.setmNote(event_title);
                    myEventDay.setmTime(eTime);
                    myEventDay.setmDescription(event_description);
                    myEventDay.setmCategory("Category");
                    myEventDay.setmSubCat("Sub Category");
                    myEventDay.setmLocationName(locationName);

                    mCalendarView.setDate(myEventDay.getCalendar());
                    mEventDays.add(myEventDay);
                    cal.clone();
            }
                mCalendarView.setEvents(mEventDays);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OutOfDateRangeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the problem with the `cal.clone()` method. I don't think it does anything. Try `cal = cal.clone()` or putting `Calendar cal = Calendar. getInstance();` inside for loop.

Comment: Can you debug at this line `mCalendarView.setEvents(mEventDays);` and check how many objects you have in `mEventDays`?

Comment: well i got it right. the problem was with the date format.